# parse an excel file to combine two sheets to make d3.js force layout node/edges json

Tags: php, json, excel, parsing, d3.js

I have an excel file, which contains two sheets, one contains the nodes and the second the links to build a d3.js force layout diagram.
For the output json file, I want keep the column headings as the key for each item.
 and put *null* for nonexistant data.
In the **links** part of the json, I prefer to take the id of the **topicA** and **topicB** from the nodes instead of putting the string name for the topic.
 Regarding the keywords, as they are separated by a comma under the keywords heading, I want to put them into this format `"keywords": ["one","two","three"]` . How can this be done in php?

structure of th the `nodes` sheet:

```
id  topic   number  file  keywords        kind
1   animals 120     file1   
2   flowers 500     file2 one,two,three,  kind1
3   nature  10      file3 one             kind2
4   humans  400     file4 three,two 
5   colors  800     file5
```

structure of the `links` sheet:

```
id  topicA   topicB   relation
1   animals  nature   15
2   flowers  animals  7
3   flowers  nature   3
4   nature   colors   1
5   colors   humans   2
6   humans   flowers  9
7   humans   nature   11
```

the desired output json:

```
{
  "nodes": [{
    "topic": "animals",
    "number": 120
    "file": "file1",
    "keywords": null,
    "kind": null
  },
  {
    "topic": "flowers",
    "number": 500
    "file": "file2",
    "keywords": ["one","two","three"],
    "kind": "kind1"
  },
  ...
  ],
  "links": [{
    "topicA": 1,
    "topicB": 3,
    "relation": 15,
    "id": 1
  },
...
  ]
}
```

Comment: this seems like a request for code, rather than help with code you have written

Comment: and i see you asked the exact same thing before. we would prefer you did not do that.